# What is comp in percolation? Python's graph-tool

Tags: python, graph-theory, graph-tool

In the [documentation](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/topology.html#graph_tool.topology.vertex_percolation) for `graph-tool` vertex percolation process, there is a quantity called `comp` defined as

> Vertex property map with component labels.

I would like to know whether that refers to the number of connected components (I am interested on that). When I run the simulation for a graph I get an object which returns always the same number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that property map just indicates to which component a vertex belongs (labelled from `0` to `C-1`, where `C` is  the number of components).

To get the number `C` of connected components you can just look a the maximum value of that property map and just add one to it.